# How to check if data is inserted in MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

I am searching from Mysql database and want to show message if record found status is FOUND else if record not found display FOUND??

```
<?php
    $status="";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {   
        $degree=$_POST["degree"];
        $mysql_host = "*******";
        $mysql_database = "**********";
        $mysql_user = "*******";
        $mysql_password = "*********";

        $conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
        if(!$conn )
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db($mysql_database)or die("cannot select DB");
        $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM studentRecord
            WHERE degree='$degree'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
        if(!$result )
        {
            $status="not found";
        }
        else
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {    
                echo  $row['name'];echo "<br>";
                echo  $row['degree'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
            $status="";
        }
        echo "<h1>" . $status . "</h1>";    
    }
?>
```

here is my form

```
<h1>Search</h1>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <div class="form_settings">
        <p>
            <select name="degree">
                <option></option>
                <option>Civil Engineering</option>
                <option>Urban & Infrastructure Engineering</option>
                <option>Petroleum Engineering</option>
                <option>Mechanical Engineering</option>
                <option>Textile Engineering</option>
                <option>Industrial & Manufacturing Engineering</option>
                <option>Automotive & Marine Engineering</option>
                <option>Electrical Engineering</option>
                <option>Computer & Information Systems Engineering</option>
                <option>Electronic Engineering</option>
                <option>Chemical Engineering</option>
                <option>Materials Engineering</option>
                <option>Metallurgical Engineering</option>
                <option>Polymer & Petrochemical Engineering</option>
                <option>Software Engineering</option>
                <option>Construction Engineering</option>
                <option>Computer Science & Information Technology</option>
            </select>
            <span style="float:right;"class="error">
        </p>
        <br>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="searchSubmit" value="SEARCH" />  
    </div>    
</form>
```

I am searching from Mysql database and want to show message if record found status is FOUND else if record not found display FOUND??

Comment: ...and what isn't working on your code?

Comment: ps, might want to cover up your username and password...

Comment: $status not showing when record not found

Comment: solved @nigro.simone has solved it

Answer (score 2):

use [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die( mysql_error() );

if( mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0 )
    echo 'not found';
else
    echo 'found';
```

**PS. mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli_* or pdo**